# How Magento creates & saves product? Need File & Function name for the same..?

Tags: database, function, magento, save, product

I am interested to know which file is used in Magento which create products in Magento?
In Magento, we create New Product from Catalog->Manage Product->Add Product.

Then after selecting product type & attribute set, we insert necessary product detials & last we press **SAVE** tab. Now I want this `file/function/code location` through which `Magento saves product in database`?

How to get product Id from that file?
Also how to get Category Id to which any particular product is assigned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following is the path of the controller file which used in the product save

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php
```

and the method used for this is public function saveAction() {}

cheers..

Thanks,
jeet

Comment: HI Jitendra, How to get category Id for which that product is get saved from ProductController.php page?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure whether this will help u a lot, but try to start your search from:

```
Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController   saveAction
```

Moreover debug_backtrace() function might help u a lot.